# Adding a name to kafka streams state store breaks

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream topology defined with a kafka table as such :

```
stream
    ... //irrelevant steps
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), customSerdes))
    .aggregate(something(), somethingElse(), Materialized.with(Serdes.String(),customSerdes))
```

I now want to query that state store dynamically for debugging purposes, which I understand requires naming the state store :

```
stream
    ... //irrelevant steps
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), customSerdes))
    .aggregate(something(), somethingElse(), 
    Materialized.<String,CustomType,KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                    as("mappings")
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withValueSerde(customSerdes))
```

However when I start it, the stream dies with the following exception

```
Exception in thread "<consumer-id>-ce730881-6504-4804-b74f-8ef981708603-StreamThread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Assigned partition <consumer-id>-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018-repartition-4 for non-subscribed topic regex pattern; subscription pattern is core.device.events.all|<consumer-id>-KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000017-repartition|<consumer-id>-mappings-repartition
```

This has been running for a while so I'd rather not lose the existing state or need to reprocess the entire topic.

Comment: Did you reset your application before restarting? https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html

Comment: No I did not, according to that link though, it should delete the internal topic so perhaps that would solve the issue. will report back. Thanks